Is there any built-in way to get the mantissa and exponent (the "scientific notation" or "E-notation" values) of a CGFloat in Swift?
I was stunned to learn there is no? immediate way to get the mantissa/exponent of a CGFloat in Swift.
(Note that I want the two values, NOT a string representation in scientific notation format.)
These hopelessly undocumented properties Double.exponent, Double.significand are on Double but that's quite different from wanting the "usual, human" mantissa/exponent. (Unless I'm drastically missing something.)
I typed out a function to do it, but doing so is crap for at least three major reasons that come to mind.
Is there a solution to this conundrum?
(*) Surprised there are not 100 questions about this issue on here!
extension CGFloat { // (ignored negatives for clarity)
    var decomp: (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        var exponent: CGFloat = 0.0
        var mantissa: CGFloat = self
        while mantissa < 1.0 {
            mantissa = mantissa * 10.0
            exponent -= 1
        }
        while mantissa >= 10.0 {
            mantissa = mantissa / 10.0
            exponent += 1
        }
        print("check ... ", self, "\(mantissa)E\(exponent)")
        return (mantissa, exponent)
    }
}

hence ..
var x: CGFloat = 0.00123
print( "yo" , x.decomp)
x = 12
print( "yo" , x.decomp)
x = 1000
print( "yo" , x.decomp)

check ...  0.00123 1.23E-3.0
yo (1.23, -3.0)
check ...  12.0 1.2E1.0
yo (1.2, 1.0)
check ...  1000.0 1.0E3.0
yo (1.0, 3.0)
(†) Minor - I return the exp as a float  since that seemed more consistent for the typical ways you'd then use such a thing, but IDK.

The exponent and significand properties of Double gives you the binary significand and exponents. After all, Double is a binary floating point type.
It seems like you want to get the base-10 exponent and significand. To do that, you should use a Decimal, which represents a base-10 number.
extension CGFloat {
    // this does not consider "special" values like infinities and NaNs
    var base10ExponentAndSignificand: (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        let decimal = Decimal(self)
        
        return (
            CGFloat(truncating: decimal.significand as NSNumber) * (decimal.isSignMinus ? -1 : 1),
            CGFloat(decimal.exponent)
        )
    }
}

This will produce integers n, m where the original number is equal to n * pow(10, m).
Scientific notation is usually written as nEm where n is a number between 1 and 10. If you want n to be between 1 and 10, I would just use log10 to calculate the exponent, instead of the looping approach shown in your question:
extension CGFloat {
    // this does not consider "special" values like infinities and NaNs
    var base10ExponentAndSignificand: (CGFloat, CGFloat) {
        guard self != 0 else { return (0, 0) }
        
        let exp = log10(self.magnitude).rounded(.down)
        let significand = self / pow(10, exp)
        
        return (significand, exp)
    }
}


My God!  So essentially the secret is to  use Decimal rather than Double!! I just didn't think of it!  I guess there was something tricky about the name "Decimal" that threw me off :)

@Fattie This is how they implemented Decimal.init(Double) in swift-corelibs-foundation. It uses loops similar to the ones you use. Not sure if this helps.

Here'a a look at the results from three ways to do it,
Be aware the mantissa is often "wrong", out by a few distant digits. This applies to all three methods. :/
0.23
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 2.3000000000000003, exponent: -1.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 2.3, normalizedExponent: -1.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 2.3000000000000005e+18, notNormalizedExponent: -19.0)
using sprintf %E
 2.300000E-01

 0.000357
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 3.5700000000000003, exponent: -4.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 3.57, normalizedExponent: -4.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 357.0, notNormalizedExponent: -6.0)
using sprintf %E
 3.570000E-04

 0.000857
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 8.57, exponent: -4.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 8.57, normalizedExponent: -4.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 857.0, notNormalizedExponent: -6.0)
using sprintf %E
 8.570000E-04

 0.000127
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 1.27, exponent: -4.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 1.27, normalizedExponent: -4.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 127.0, notNormalizedExponent: -6.0)
using sprintf %E
 1.270000E-04

 66.0
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 6.6, exponent: 1.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 6.6, normalizedExponent: 1.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 66.0, notNormalizedExponent: 0.0)
using sprintf %E
 6.600000E+01

 0.2
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 2.0, exponent: -1.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 2.0, normalizedExponent: -1.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 2.0, notNormalizedExponent: -1.0)
using sprintf %E
 2.000000E-01

 0.6
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 6.0, exponent: -1.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 5.999999999999999, normalizedExponent: -1.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 6.0, notNormalizedExponent: -1.0)
using sprintf %E
 6.000000E-01

 0.8
using 'division' method
 (mantissa: 8.0, exponent: -1.0)
using log method
 (normalizedSignificand: 8.0, normalizedExponent: -1.0)
via Decimal method (gives 'random' pairs, not scientific notation pairs)
 (notNormalizedSignificand: 8.0, notNormalizedExponent: -1.0)
using sprintf %E
 8.000000E-01


It does seem to be the case that using %E with the string formatter magically "works" in all cases. The other three don't "work".

So you just don't like the minuscule errors like 0.0000000000000003? That's just because floating-point math is broken. The Decimal approach has the same problem (but perhaps less frequently) for some particular values (try 0.23). You can never precisely convert binary to base-10 for all numbers. This is also the reason why the Decimal.init(String) initialiser is much preferred over the one that takes a Double.

"So you just don't like the minuscule errors like" Sure, that's what I'm referring to. There are any number of cases where you need to avoid that.  And yes I'm sadly aware of how floating point math is the bane of life :) Ah, thanks for pointing out the Decimal indeed ahs the same problem, I didn't know - edited this demo.

I just did a quick test and indeed the %E seems to always "work".  I wonder if they very simply round it to 6 places or if there's some other trickery at hand!

The criteria is probably “as many digits as needed to distinguish that number from its neighbours (plus/minus 1 ulp)”. See Java’s Double.toString for example. https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-
